# when I try to get SHA-1 number from command or android studio it gives me an error

Tags: java, macos, android-studio, macos-mojave, java-12

when I try to get SHA-1 number it gives me an error

```
I typed in;
keytool -list -v \

And then typed in;
-alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore
```

It gives me this error below;

```
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist: 
/Users/FLT/.android/debug.keystore
java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist: 
/Users/FLT/.android/debug.keystore
at 
java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.doCommands(Main.java:899)
at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.run(Main.java:409)
at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.main(Main.java:402)
```

In my JavaVirtualMachines there is only KEYTOOL not debug.keystore

My JavaVirtualMachines is located in Macintosh not in my USER;

```
Macintosh HD/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk- 
12.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/bin

I don’t know in which folder debug.keystore is located.

but when I go to command and type
cd ~/
ls
ls -al

It’s there in the list
```

Answer (score 0):

This command worked for me:

`keytool -list -keystore debug.keystore`